# Not in scope 'C'

Tags: haskell

```
fold1 ((c, xs):rest) ys = Just [(c, ys)]
fold1 ((c, xs):rest) ys = if xs == ys then Just [(c, ys)] else fold1 rest ys
```

Hello,
in the 1st line is there a way to modify `((c, xs):rest) ys` in a way that `xs` and `rest` would be null?

Comment: It doesn't exist in the first line because the first parameter is an empty list. What value would you expect it to have?

Comment: i know. on the 2nd line where `fold1 ((c, xs):rest) ys` i actually want to say if xs is empty then return `Just [(c, ys)]`

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell your pattern matches are exclusive to the particular definition they're declared in.  It's like a local variable to a function or method in any other language, it can't be accessed outside of that scope on purpose.  Consider each pattern match statement to be a separate function definition.

Would you rather be doing this instead?

```
fold1 [] ys = Nothing
fold1 [(c, xs)] ys = Just [(c, ys)]
fold1 ((c, xs):rest) ys = if xs == ys then Just [(c, ys)] else fold1 rest ys
```

I'm guessing (possibly incorrectly) that you are wanting the last result before the list is empty, so instead of waiting for the list to be empty just pattern match on when the list only contains one element.  When someone passes in an empty list as the first argument just return `Nothing` instead, it indicates that you can't do anything meaningful with the input.

Comment: hello, i just want the case where `xs` and `rest` are empty

Comment: @gioug123 then replace `xs` with `[]` in the case I added.

Comment: @gioug123 Since this answer solved your question don't forget to accept it, and also welcome to SO; make sure to check out the [Tour](/tour) and [Help Center](/help).